Loading JSON file in NextJs Header component results in Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
I am having a NextJs app using the app router and a pretty simple Layout.tsx:
import Footer from "@repo/shared/footer";
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import Head from "next/head";
import HeaderComponent from "../../_components/HeaderComponent";
import "./../../styles/styles.scss";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { lang },
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { lang: string };
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang={lang}>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <HeaderComponent lang={lang} />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </body>

        <Analytics />
      </html>
    </>
  );
}

The HeaderComponent has "use client" and loads the content based on the current language:
async function getHeaderContent(lang: string): Promise<HeaderContent> {
  const fullPath = `${process.cwd()}/src/_lib/${lang}/header-content.json`;
  const fileContents = await fs.readFile(fullPath, "utf8");
  return JSON.parse(fileContents);
}

This works perfectly for every page inside my app but apparently not for my header. On localhost everything is fine, but when I deploy it to vercel I am seeing the following error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/var/task/apps/myapp/src/_lib/en/header-content.json' at async
open (node:internal/fs/promises:636:25) at async Object.readFile
(node:internal/fs/promises:1246:14) at async v
(/var/task/apps/myapp/.next/server/chunks/165.js:1:5041) at
async g
(/var/task/apps/myapp/.next/server/chunks/165.js:1:4599) {
errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path:
'/var/task/apps/myapp/src/_lib/en/header-content.json', digest:
'1329482108' }

When I add the  to each individual page, it works. The path is correct for 100% and the file also shows up in vercel at the correct folder location.
Edit: This is my folder structure and in the en/de folders are my json files:


i think in cases where the file is not found, the structure would be nice to have.  The Imports look kinda wild.

I updated my post to show the folder structure. But I basically just followed the NextJs best practices
